# Vectorizing the Sum of a Triple For Loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Currently, I am trying to build the matrix Alpha through this triple-loop:

```
Alpha = zeros(a_length, b_length);   
for a = 1:a_length
  for b = 1:b_length
      for c = 1:c_length
          Alpha(a,b) = Alpha(a,b) + Beta(c,a) * Gamma(b,c);
      end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to pass in two vectors to the Beta and Gamma Matrices, such that I can construct the entirety of Alpha in a single, vectorized line of elegant code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use simple `matrix multiplication` to your rescue -

```
Alpha = (Gamma*Beta).'
```

Or this way -

```
Alpha = Beta.'*Gamma.'
```

Or a bit complicated `bsxfun` based approach -

```
Alpha = sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(Gamma,[3 1 2]),permute(Beta,[2 3 1])),3)
```

And if you want to avoid one `permute` from the earlier `bsxfun` approach -

```
Alpha = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,Gamma,permute(Beta,[3 1 2])),2)).'
```

Or this -

```
Alpha = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,Beta.',permute(Gamma,[3 2 1])),2))
```

Comment: How would you incorporate the Alpha(a,b) term that needs to be added each time?

Comment: @jsc123 Basically each element of the matrix multiplication result corresponds to `Alpha(a,b)`. Did you test out the code?

Comment: Why do you put the Gamma in quotes in the second version?

Comment: @jsc123 In `Alpha = Beta.'*Gamma.'` I am multiplying the transpose of `Beta` and the transpose of `Gamma`. So those quotes are actually transposes. Read more about it here - http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html