# Generating a grid in matlab with a general number of dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

### **Problem**

I have a vector `w` containing `n` elements. I do not know `n` in advance.

I want to generate an `n`-dimensional grid `g` whose values range from `grid_min` to `grid_max` and obtain the "dimension-wise" product of `w` and `g`.

How can I do this for an arbitrary `n`?

---

### **Examples**

For simplicity, let's say that `grid_min = 0` and `grid_max = 5`.

**Case: `n=1`**

```
>> w = [0.75];
>> g = 0:5

ans =

     0     1     2     3     4     5

>> w * g

ans =

         0    0.7500    1.5000    2.2500    3.0000    3.7500
```

**Case: `n=2`**

```
>> w = [0.1, 0.2];
>> [g1, g2] = meshgrid(0:5, 0:5)

g1 =

     0     1     2     3     4     5
     0     1     2     3     4     5
     0     1     2     3     4     5
     0     1     2     3     4     5
     0     1     2     3     4     5
     0     1     2     3     4     5


g2 =

     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5     5

>> w(1) * g1 + w(2) * g2

ans =

         0    0.1000    0.2000    0.3000    0.4000    0.5000
    0.2000    0.3000    0.4000    0.5000    0.6000    0.7000
    0.4000    0.5000    0.6000    0.7000    0.8000    0.9000
    0.6000    0.7000    0.8000    0.9000    1.0000    1.1000
    0.8000    0.9000    1.0000    1.1000    1.2000    1.3000
    1.0000    1.1000    1.2000    1.3000    1.4000    1.5000
```

Now suppose a user passes in the vector `w` and we do not know how many elements (`n`) it contains. How can I create the grid and obtain the product?

Comment: Kudos for such a clearly expressed question

Comment: If you run into memory problems for "large" `n` (this seems to explode real quick anyway...) you could get a tiny bit further if you take *Luis*' approach and modify it to only generate one of the `n` `gg`s and sum it in a `for`-loop while permuting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
%// Data:
grid_min = 0;
grid_max = 5;
w = [.1 .2 .3];

%// Let's go:    
n = numel(w);
gg = cell(1,n);
[gg{:}] = ndgrid(grid_min:grid_max);
gg = cat(n+1, gg{:});
result = sum(bsxfun(@times, gg, shiftdim(w(:), -n)), n+1);
```

*How this works*:

The grid (variable `gg`) is generated with [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html), using as output a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of `n` elements obtained from a cell array. The resulting `n`-dimensional arrays (`gg{1}`, `gg{2}` etc) are contatenated along the `n+1`-th dimension (using [`cat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)), which turns `gg` into an `n+1`-dimensional array. The vector `w` is reshaped into the `n+1`-th dimension ([`shiftdim`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html)), multiplied by `gg` using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), and the results are summed along the `n+1`-th dimension.

*Edit:*

Following @Divakar's insightful comment, the last line can be replaced by

```
sz_gg = size(gg);
result = zeros(sz_gg(1:end-1));
result(:) = reshape(gg,[],numel(w))*w(:);
```

which results in a significant speedup, because Matlab is even better at matrix multiplication than at `bsxfun` (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26905520/2586922) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23911671/2586922)).

Comment: These tensor-multiplications should really be built-ins! BTW: It wouldn't be a good idea to change the answer, as this is more natural, but as a sidenote: for `n==2` it's actually the transpose of the OP's question due to `meshgrid` vs. `ndgrid`. I'm pretty sure that `ndgrid` is what he really wants.

Comment: `sz_gg = size(gg);
result = zeros(sz_gg(1:end-1));
result(:) = reshape(gg,[],numel(w))*w(:);` seems to be much more memory efficient and shows good speedup.

Comment: @knedlsepp Good point! As you say, I think I'll leave it as it is

Comment: @Divakar Good alternative! However, it doesn't seem to speed much up. But I only tested with `tic`, `toc`

Comment: @Divakar: Octave's JIT doesn't seem that good, so ideone profiling won't give the best results, but on my machine [this `for`-approach](https://ideone.com/REJyDQ) will even be faster for large n. (Though not as pretty.)

Comment: @Divakar You're right. I was too sloppy and didn't apply iterations. With your code, the speedup in my computer is even greater than yours . Edited!

Comment: @Divakar I remember you often use this technique of substituting `bsxfun` by matrix product. And I think you had a "canonical" answer for that, but I can't find it. Can you tell me what it is, so that I can link it in my edited answer?

Comment: Well, I am not sure if I had any canonical answer for replacing `sum(bsxfun(@times..)` with `matrix-multiplication`. See if you meant one of these - [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26994722/3293881), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27142285/3293881), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26905520/3293881)

Comment: @Divakar It was 3, and the one you were based on there. Thanks!